# How to run mutilple Windows CMD commands with python?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I was trying to run multiple CMD commands from a Python program using os.system, but i am able to run only first command, second command it not getting executed. Can you please suggest an alternative?

My commands:

```
cd ..
cd Users\xyz
\abc\pqr.exe
```

Script I tried:

```
os.system('cmd /c "cd .. & cd Users\xyz"')
```

Comment: Are you trying to just run the command and forget about it or are you trying to capture return data also?

Comment: First things first, commands 1. & 2. can be just a single command, ```CD ..\Users\xyz```. Next, 3. isn't a 'CMD command', it is, (I presume), a commandline executable file. That means whilst it may work in cmd.exe, it is certainly not limited to it. Of course you could get rid of ```CD ..\Users\xyz``` too and simply have a single command, ```cmd.exe /D /C "Start "" /D "..\Users\xyz" "..\Users\xyz\abc\pqr.exe""```.

Comment: It may even be, that you do not even need to run `cmd.exe` at all, and just run `pqr.exe` with, if required, _(it shouldn't be)_, the appropriate working directory. I should also say that you should not be using relative paths unless you have first specified the current working directory, (for it to be relative to).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `subprocess` module and execute your commands like this:

`subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])`

Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 0):

use list to store all your command you want to execute and iterate through it using a for loop while using `os.system` to. execute your program

```
commands = ['cd ..','cd Users\xyz','\abc\pqr.exe']
        
for command in commands:
  os.system(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops... It is easy to execute each of those CMD commands with `os.system`, but  you will be disappointed by the outcome. The problem is that each command will be executed inside its own process, and the Current Working Directory is *local* to the process.

So here is what will happen:

- execution of `os.system('cd ..')`

  - the Python interpretor of the script starts a new process
  - the current directory of *that second process* is changed
  - the second process gets closed
  - the current directory of the calling script has not changed

You can do that in a *shell* (what cmd.exe is), because the `cd` command is an internal command that is directly executed by the shell. But no external command is allowed to change the current shell directory nor its environment.

That means that you only have 2 ways here:

1. use *internal commands* (meaning here Python functions like `os.chdir`) to actually change the current directory or the environment of your script - this one is easy and robust
2. start one single `cmd.exe` shell and feed its standard input streams with your different commands

While the second way could looks appealing, it is in fact much harder if you want to handle the return messages from the various commands, because you will communicate through pipes which can introduce buffering. So you can only be sure that all the output will be available... when the child command will be ended!

Answer (score 0):

you can list your commands as a list and use the `subprocess`

```
command = ';'.join(
    [
        'cd ..',
        'cd',
        'Users\xyz',
        'pwd',
        'ls'
        
    ])
result_proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = result_proc.communicate()
print(output.decode('utf-8'))
```